# Is Blazor-United SEO friendly?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a website (an official corporate website, but it relies heavily on jQuery), and because its rendering speed is very slow, I plan to replace it from jQuery to Blazor-United(Although I'm well aware that it might be quicker to fix some of the issues with the jQuery code, I'd like to completely refactor the entire project). However, the main purpose of this website is to promote the company (more for SEO). I am not sure whether Blazor-United is SEO-friendly and whether search engines can properly crawl Blazor-United's html data. There seems to be no relevant information and answers on the Internet. Can anyone with experience tell me?

I know Blazor Server is SEO friendly, but Blazor WASM is not SEO friendly. But in this project, I plan to use automatic rendering mode and I'm not sure if it will be SEO friendly in automatic rendering mode.

I know it's not the right place to discuss programming questions that don't involve coding, but I can't think of any other way to find this answer.

Thanks

Comment: It has the potential to be as SEO-friendly as you make it - really depends on the page/component rendering model you pick. Blazor Server-side Rendering (not Server) is going to be the best SEO experience for the least work.

Comment: @BenSampica I have learned about the principle of automatic rendering of Blazor United. It will use Blazor Server during the first visit and Blazor WASM in subsequent visits. I think if I use Blazor Server for the first time, search engines will definitely be able to crawl it. But when search engines visit my website for the second time or later, will Blazor change to WASM mode, causing it to not be crawled by search engines? ?

Comment: SEO depends on  prerendering,also If your component is in InteractiveAuto render mode,it would always be in InterActiveServer untill  Blazor Bundle is downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) mentioned:

> Prerendering can improve Search Engine Optimization  by rendering
> content for the initial HTTP response that search engines can use to
> calculate page rank.

Prerendering would be enabled by default when you call

```
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveAuto]
```

You could control  content in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps follow this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-8.0),add content for  Search Engine Optimization as below:

```
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<HeadContent>
     <meta  name="description" content="SEO-Friendly Home Page"/>
</HeadContent>
```

Other [article](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-create-an-seo-friendly-blazor-webassembly-application)/[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1GI2vuD_nQ) related,hopes help

Comment: The key is whether the search engine will download the Blazor Bundle. What I mean is that if the search engine downloads the Blazor Bundle, it will be changed to WASM rendering. If rendered through WASM, some traditional search engines, such as Baidu instead of Google, will be completely unable to crawl it. So I have an idea, can it be determined through UA? If it is a search engine's UA, then Blazor Server will be forced to respond?

Comment: It's mainly related with how search engine works,I suggest you add a tag related,also,it may differ in different search engine,an article related:https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/pre-render-blazor-webassembly-at-build-time-to-optimize-for-search-engines#summary